# Silverlight app fails to load because 4.1 plugin installed and 5.1 required. Update not automatic?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0, silverlight-plugin

I've written a Silverlight 5 app. When users with the Silverlight 4.1 plugin instaled visit my page, the app fails to load.

Should Silverlight not automatically download the latest version of the plugin if my .xap file requires it?

It doesn't appear in Windows Update either.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Webproject for your Silverlight Application you can specify in the Default.aspx the Minimun Runtime Version of Silverlight that needs to be installed to run your application.

In the Default.aspx is an entry like:

```
<param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="5.0.60401.0" />
<param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
<a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=5.0.60401.0" style="text-decoration: none">
  <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight"
  style="border-style: none" />
</a>
```

This setting indicates that at least the Version 5.0.60401.0 must be installed for your application. If the client opens your silverlight application and uses a lower version then an installation dialog is displayed to install the needed silverlight version.

Answer (score 0):

Nope.  Installing Silverlight is a manual activity that the user/desktop support must perform.

Silverlight will tell you that you've got the wrong version but it is up to the user to actually upgrade it.